# Java generics - Type unimportant

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

(Sorry for the title, I couldn't come up with anything better)

I'm working on a big project filled with references to raw types and I'm trying to get rid of them.
The problem is that in most cases we don't really know the actual type.
An example is probably the best way to explain.

Consider:

```
public interface Event<S, D> {
  S getSource();
  D getData();
}

public interface Listener<E extends Event<?, ?>> {
  void onEvent(E event);
}

public interface Listenable<E extends Event<?, ?>> {
  void addListener(Listener<E> listener);
  void removeListener(Listener<E> listener);
}

public class DataAccess implements Listenable {

  ...

  public void addListener(final Listener listener) {
    eventHandler.addListener(listener);
  }

  public void removeListener(final Listener listener) {
    eventHandler.removeListener(listener);
  }
}
```

DataAccess doesn't really care what type of listener we pass in as it can receive events with different types. I suspect generics is used here in the wrong way and probably Listener and Listenable don't need to be generic?

I thought of changing Listener to

```
public interface Listener {
  void onEvent(Class<? extends Event<?, ?>> event);
}
```

But then onEvent won't have access to Event's methods.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you just change the signature of `addListener` and `removeListener` to `public void addListener(final Listener<?> listener)`?

Comment: `DataAccess` *has to care*, as it promises to deliver the specific type `X` to a `Listener<X>` and nothing else. Everything else must be considered broken (and will brake at runtime). Or, well, you remove the generic type parameter from `Listener` and `Listenable`. But why you change the parameter type from `Event` to `Class` is above me.

Comment: If you really don't care Event's parameters at this level, then why not creating a superclass without those generics fe: "Event" <-- "DataEvent<S, D>", and then you don't pollute Listener model with parameters not used.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would remain the most generic as possible in interfaces and I would let the implementations define the explicit types otherwise if in your interfaces you only use the wildcards you can't benefit anymore of the power of the generics in your implementations.

So I would have something like this

```
public interface Event<S, D> {
    S getSource();
    D getData();
}

public interface Listener<E extends Event<S, D>, S, D> {
    void onEvent(E event);
}

public interface Listenable<E extends Event<S, D>, S, D> {
    void addListener(Listener<E, S, D> listener);
    void removeListener(Listener<E, S, D> listener);
}
```

Thanks to this much more flexible approach, if you have implementations that accept specific events you can then narrow the type of allowed events otherwise you can still use wildcards to support any events.

Comment: But then implementations of Listener would have to specify the types. And that's another problem because a Listener can work on different kinds of event. That's why I'm saying the use of generics here is wrong.

Comment: in case the events have nothing in common then you will use the wild card in implementations, but in case the events are of the same type (share the same inteferface) you can then use a more appropriate generic type. The point here is if you use wild card everywhere simply don't use generics are they will be useless. Typically the other answer is a good proof

Answer (score 1):

If `Listener` can work with any kind of event, then the right way to define it is :

```
public interface Listener {
  void onEvent(Event<?, ?> event);
}
```

You can then call `getSource()` and `getData()` in `onEvent()` implementations, but they will return values of type `Object` and you may have to do some casting in order to do anything useful in your listeners.

The fact that listeners can process any kind of events makes the whole S & D genericity kind of pointless. @NicolasFilotto's answer shows how a sound design should look like, but maybe you don't have much choice.

Comment: I came to the same solution (if so we can call it). You got the point of my question: looks like they put in the generics just 'because'. It's not used and there is plenty of casts every where.

Comment: @algiogia well, sorry to read that. What you can do to mitigate this is to build your whole generic model with full genericity and type-specific listeners, then put your current implementations into loosely typed subclasses (using `Object` and `?` wildcards). That way you have a good model for future developments and you don't have to change too many things.

Answer (score 1):

Given the current declaration, I can write the following without the compiler objecting:

```
void example(DataAccess eventSource) {
    abstract class MyEvent implements Event<BigInteger,String>{}
    eventSource.addListener(new Listener<MyEvent>() {
        public void onEvent(MyEvent event) {
            BigInteger bi=event.getSource();
            String str=event.getData();
        }
    });
}
```

Not only is it hard to imagine that the event source appropriately delivers the expected event type, it hasn’t even enough information to decide to never invoke that listener, as the only way to find out the expected type is Reflection, which has several restrictions when it comes to generic types.

The conclusion is that you can’t provide such a flexibility. Normally, an event source should know what kind of events it can deliver. In this case, it should declare it like:

```
public class DataAccessEvent implements Event<DataAccess,SpecificDataType> {
  public DataAccess getSource() {
    // ...
  }
  public SpecificDataType getData() {
    // ...
  }
}
public class DataAccess implements Listenable<DataAccessEvent> {

  public void addListener(Listener<DataAccessEvent> listener) {
    eventHandler.addListener(listener);
  }

  public void removeListener(Listener<DataAccessEvent> listener) {
    eventHandler.removeListener(listener);
  }
}
```

Note that the correct method signature is now demanded due to the class declaration. There’s no sense in registering listeners for event types that the source will never deliver.

---

The same is also possible without exporting the actual event type, e.g.

```
public class DataAccess implements Listenable<Event<DataAccess,SpecificDataType>> {

  public void addListener(Listener<Event<DataAccess,SpecificDataType>> listener) {
    eventHandler.addListener(listener);
  }

  public void removeListener(Listener<Event<DataAccess,SpecificDataType>> listener) {
    eventHandler.removeListener(listener);
  }
}
```

---

To support listeners which can handle broader types, you would have to declare the interface as

```
public interface Listenable<E extends Event<?, ?>> {
  void addListener(Listener<? super E> listener);
  void removeListener(Listener<? super E> listener);
}
```

So these methods also accept listeners which can handle super types of the type that this source might deliver. This includes listeners which are capable of consuming `Event<?,?>`. Of course, the implementing classes have to insert the `? super …` into their signatures as well.

Comment: The problem is that DataAccess will fire different subclass of Event. I suppose I can have them all extend the same interface extending Event...

Comment: The straight-forward solution is to declare a common base class of all possible events. It must be prevented that you can add a listener which can handle only one specific subclass, but receives another subclass. So demanding that all listeners can handle the common base class, is the simplest choice. Otherwise, you need another parameter to support filtering, e.g. `<X extends E> void addListener(Class<X> which, Listener<X> listener);`, but that complicates the implementation a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Why not :

```
public class DataAccess implements Listenable<Event<?,?>>
    {


          private Listenable<Event<?, ?>> eventHandler;

          public void addListener(final Listener<Event<?,?>> listener) 
          {
            eventHandler.addListener(listener);
          }

          public void removeListener(final Listener<Event<?,?>> listener) 
          {
            eventHandler.removeListener(listener);
          }

    }
```

`E extends Event<?,?>` is an `Event<?,?>` in the end, and you need to specifically ask for the type in `onEvent`, cast it to that type to call a subtype specific method.

Here is example code that conveys the idea :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TestGeneric
{

    private Listenable<Event<?, ?>> eventHandler = new MyListenable();


    public void run()
    {
        MyEvent<Object, Object> myEvent = new MyEvent<Object, Object>();

        MyExtendedEvent<Object, Object> myExtendedEvent = new MyExtendedEvent<Object, Object>();

        eventHandler.addListener( new MyListener() );


        ((MyListenable)eventHandler).fire( myEvent );
        ((MyListenable)eventHandler).fire( myExtendedEvent );
    }

    class MyListenable implements Listenable<Event<?,?>>
    {

        private List<Listener<Event<?, ?>>> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener<Event<?, ?>>>();

        public void addListener(Listener<Event<?, ?>> listener) 
        {
            listeners.add( listener );

        }

        public void removeListener(Listener<Event<?, ?>> listener) 
        {
            listeners.remove( listener );

        }

        public void fire( Event<?,?> event )
        {
            for ( Listener<Event<?, ?>> listener : listeners )
            {
                listener.onEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }


    class MyEvent<S, D> implements Event<S, D>
    {

        public S getSource() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public D getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void printStatement() 
        {
            System.out.println( "Hi there from MyEvent!" );

        }

    }

    class MyExtendedEvent<S, D> implements ExtendedEvent<S, D>
    {

        public S getSource() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public D getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void printStatement() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void printStatementFromExtendedEvent() 
        {
            System.out.println( "Hi there from extended event!");

        }

    }

    public interface ExtendedEvent<S, D> extends Event<S, D>
    {
        void printStatementFromExtendedEvent();
    }

    class MyListener implements Listener<Event<?,?>>
    {

        public void onEvent(Event<?, ?> event) 
        {
            if ( event instanceof ExtendedEvent )
            {
                ExtendedEvent<?, ?> extEvent = ( ExtendedEvent<?, ?> )event;
                extEvent.printStatementFromExtendedEvent();
            }
            else
            {
                event.printStatement();
            }

        }



    }




}
```